# How to use currying to create HoC in React and connect to the Redux store at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, currying

I'm using React and Redux with `react-redux`, and I'm creating in React a High order Component that I want to connect to the Redux store, like this:

```
const HoC = parameter => WrappedComponent => 
    return class WithSelected extends Component {

    // ..some use of 'parameter'

    render() { 

         return <WrappedComponent />

     }

  [...]

  const exportComponent = compose(
      connect(mapStateToProps),
      HoC
   )

 export default exportComponent;
```

and

```
import Component from '../Component'
import exportComponent from '../file'

const componentToExport = exportComponent('someValue')(Component);
```

Now, this approach gives this error:

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Btw if I don't use currying creating the Hoc, it works, like this:

```
const HoC = (parameter, WrappedComponent)  => [etc]
```

and

```
import Component from '../Component'
import exportComponent from '../file'

const componentToExport = exportComponent('someValue', Component);
```

It works. But how can I use currying creating HoC in React and use Redux at the same time?

Comment: in this HOC doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#use-hocs-for-cross-cutting-concerns

It looks like the line is ```return class extends Component``` instead of ```return class ClassName extends Component``` have you tried that?

Comment: `compose` is from redux?

Comment: @Dupocas yes is from Redux

Comment: @ZekeHernandez yes but it's the same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with currying an `HOC`. The following is a valid high order component

```
const withHoc = param => Component => props =>{
  return <Component {...props} foo={param} />
}
```

Your problem is `compose`. Your right-most argument which will provide the signature for the resulting composed function is actually evaluating to another `HOC` not the component itself.

---

You should `connect` the returned component

```
const HoC = parameter => WrappedComponent => connect(...)(props =>{
    /*...*/
})
```

Returning a class based component is the same as returning a functional one

```
const HoC = parameter => WrappedComponent => connect(...)(class X extends Component{
    render(){ return <div /> }
})
```

Just isn't that pretty though

Comment: Ok but what if I want to use `return class WithSelected extends Component [etc]` like in the original example?

Comment: Updated the answer